# how to reconcile hyperref with seminar so that A4 in portrait mode with centered content is generated?

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, seminar

When using the `seminar` package to generate slides with notes underneath the slides, while also using the `hyperref` package, it generates the page in landscape mode. This used to work with older `pdflatex` and older `seminar` package.

Here is code that demonstrates the problem:

```tex
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \pdfhorigin=1sp
  \pdfvorigin=1sp
  \paperwidth=297truemm
  \paperheight=210truemm
}

\documentclass[a4,article]{seminar}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% remove slide label
\renewcommand{\slidelabel}{}

% reduce text width so it does not extend beyond the slide width
\setlength{\textwidth}{0.9\textwidth}

\centerslidesfalse

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}
\centerslidestrue
\begin{center}
\title{\LARGE Foo}
\author{(foo)}
\date{Version: \rm\today}
\maketitle

\vspace{2ex}
Foo bar\\

\end{center}
\end{slide}

\begin{itemize}
\item Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar
Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar Foo bar
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

When I run this on macOS with pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012), LaTeX2e <2011/06/27> and seminar 2008/10/15, 1.5, this generates the intended PDF - A4, portrait, centered.

When I run this on Debian Linux with pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex) and seminar 2021/07/01, 1.63a, this generates the PDF in landscape mode, with the output aligned to the left.

This was discovered while using Github Actions Linux runner (`ubuntu-latest` that installed TeX Live using `apt`) that generated the PDF (the above code is heavily minimized from the original to demonstrate the problem) and I noticed that there was change in behavior sometime between November 2022 and March 2023. Unfortunately the logs are no longer accessible to identify what exactly has changed in the LaTeX distribution used in the runner.

Removing the `hyperref` package solves the problem, however I need the functionality that the package provides.

I tried adding `portrait` to the `seminar` package options, however this corrupts the page.

How do I make `hyperref` work with `seminar` so that it generates the PDF as A4 in portrait mode with the output centered as it used to be ?

The generated PDF documents and the code is available on https://github.com/vladak/seminar_a4/tree/main

Comment: Your \AtBeginDocument is too late, hyperref has then already set the mediabox as top-level hook additions are always last. Use e.g. `\AddToHook{class/seminar/after}{...}`. Or use a label `\AtBeginDocument[seminar]{...}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would the geometry package also work to set the page size?

Comment: @Teepeemm sure. This here is mainly a question of timing. Hyperref sets the mediabox with whatever values of paper size it finds active.

Comment: The `\AtBeginDocument[seminar]{...}` works, thanks. However I am not sure why and whether this is the best solution, esp. long term. I wonder if the `geometry` could/should fix this as well.